# REGEX rule to validate a domain field

Tags: regex, validation

For one of the products I offer it is only available to people with certain domain extensions.

On the order form there is a field for them to enter their domain, and the system I am using does allow me to validate that field before continuing the order process.

I can add a 'Validation REGEX' to be run on the value entered in the domain field.

The TDLs that are supported are: .com, .net, .org, .biz, .info, .name, .tv, .cc, .me, .pro, .mobi, .cm, .co, .com.co, .nom.co, .net.co, .ws

I am trying to find out what REGEX validation to use to determine if the domain entered in the field matches one of those TLDs.

I can't change any of the code for this task. I just have a field to enter the REGEX validation rule.

I appreciate any ideas or suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a domain they enter, use

```
\.(com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|cm|co|ws)$
```

This matches a domain *ending* in a point followed by one of the TLD's you specified.

Since you're already allowing .co as a TLD, there's no need to check for com.co, nom.co, or net.co; they're valid since they end in .co.

Comment: wouldn't this allow things like `.asfasfassfas.co` `helloTheremyFriend.co` and so on?

Comment: Yes it would. And your second example is in fact a valid domain name.  
However, the requirement was to restrict the input to certain TLD's. The input _could_ be further validated to resemble something like an actual domain, but that is not what was asked.

Comment: then it would be correct, I thought he wanted to match only the TLD.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure what function/method is used by the system to check the domain against the regex rule, the field is just labelled "Regular Expression Validation String". I put in this rule, but the domain name sadfasfdasf.com failed the validation. Since it is a permitted TLD that one should have passed.

Comment: Actually, I think it does work if I put a forward slash before and after your string. Testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for:

Extendings only:

```
^\.(?i)(net.co|nom.co|com.co|com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|co|cm|ws)$
```

name.extedning:

```
\.(?i)(net.co|nom.co|com.co|com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|co|cm|ws)$
```

Comment: This matches only if _just_ the TLD (including the dot in front of it) was entered. It also matches a single dot.

Comment: @SQB oh didn't notice I had an additional `|` at the end, thx.

Comment: Also, you're matching .nom, which isn't a valid TLD as specified by asker.

Comment: @SQB O_o true, I had to leave it there by mistake when changing the order of the pattern, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\s]+(\.(?i)(com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|cm|co|nom|ws|com.co|nom.co|net.co))$)
```